# Initialize int to 0 or not?

Tags: java, android, primitive-types

In the android source code I see they define four variables as

```
protected int mPaddingRight = 0;
protected int mPaddingLeft = 0;
protected int mPaddingTop;
protected int mPaddingBottom;
```

In Java, what is the difference in initializing a variable to 0 or not? I don’t understand that in some compilers I cannot do a comparison unless I initialize the field. But that is not the case here. Does this have to do with optimization? Or is this just inconsistent/bad coding practice?

Comment: No difference - int members are initialized to zero by default.

Comment: I would still initialize to `0` if I wanted them to be 0, though. And since I do it, you should too!

Comment: fwiw: Using Java in Visual Studio Code for some algorithm practice throws this error if an int is not initialized 
`"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The local variable myVar1 may not have been initialized"`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to [Java primitive data types tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html): When **fields** are declared without initialization, the compiler will assign a sensible default value. Typically, this default would be zero or null, based on the data type.

```
byte    0
short   0
int     0
long    0L
float   0.0f
double  0.0d
char    '\u0000'
String (or any object)      null
boolean false
```

A good practice: initialize values before using them to prevent unexpected behavior.

Comment: Wow, lots of great answers. So I pick the oldest and up vote the others.

Comment: local variables are not initialized in java. See the same Java primitive data types tutorial mentioned above. Field variables (instance variables) are initialized but not locals.

Answer (score 4):

Local variables must be initialized before use.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    System.out.println(x);
  }
}
```

This code does not compile. However instance variables (or class in case they are `static`) have default values.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good coding practice to initialize variables.

From Oracle Docs:

> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared.
>   Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a
>   reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default
>   will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such
>   default values, however, is generally considered bad programming
>   style.

The benefits of **initializing the variables** are as following:

1. Makes it easier to follow your code
2. Makes life easier for static analysis tools.
3. Most of the prevalent design patterns asks you to initialize variable to a default value, so that the programmer knows exactly to which value the variable is initialized.
4. It is always good practice to initialize variables to prevent undefined behavior later in the program.
5. Debugging becomes easier if you initialize the variables.

Comment: Hmm. There is not exactly "undefined behavior" here. All well-specified. Static analysis tools can deal with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, *no there is no difference*. They'll be initalized with 0 implicitly. However if you use good IDE or have other tools, it would be really easy for you to search and replace `= 0;` with `= SomeOtherValueHere;`.

Also I think it is a good practice to always initialzie your variables before you access them.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out that class properties are initialized to default values for you.

So, semantically, there is no difference if you set them explicitly to 0 (or, for object properties, set those to null.)

However, there may in fact be a difference at the bytecode level. There is no guarantee that code that differs only in class properties that are implicitly vs. explicitly set to default values will have exactly the same bytecode.

Older versions of the JDK used to generate larger and longer code for explicit initialization, which was easy to check with `javap`. (This fact was occasionally used as the basis for interview questions.) I haven't checked recent versions of the JDK to see if this is still the case.

Comment: As for whether you _should_ initialize class properties in this manner, even to their already known default values, this is treading into holy war territory. My feelings are that explicit default initializers are noise and should be omitted. If a property needs a non-default initializer, and the design doesn't want static initializers or constructors (for whatever reason) then I suppose one could do this as long as there are comments for why magic values are being used. Still, every Java shop I've worked at never did this. Those C# devs, however, they initialize _everything_.

Comment: Longer code for explicit initalization ? And I thought I know Java :D